# What's the grammar behind どうせ?

Tags: grammar

I saw a few bits here and elsewhere on it, but I have yet to find something that explains its usage, in detail(e.g. in positive and negative contexts and in different tenses). Anyone know?

Comment: Which dictionaries have you tried and what have you found so far?

Comment: As far as I can remember, I haven't seen this particular term in any of my physical books, and the most comprehensive view I've gotten of it was at http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%9B , and even that still leaves me mystified on the exact grammar mechanics of it

Comment: References: http://journals.linguisticsociety.org/elanguage/pragmatics/article/download/354/354-641-1-PB.pdf and http://ci.nii.ac.jp/els/110001057681.pdf?id=ART0001218787&type=pdf&lang=en&host=cinii&order_no=&ppv_type=0&lang_sw=&no=1483413661&cp=

Answer (score 1):

It only means "either way", "anyhow", "anyway", etc with a *fatalist* nuance, hence it can sound negative for some.

You can find it as other forms like どっちにしろ or どっちにせよ.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm sure the underlying grammar makes the analogy a rather liberal one, I have always tended to feel that these were similar to patters in English that use "be". That is, an old form of the subjunctive:

Ａであれ、Ｂであれ、なんでもいい。
Be it A, or be it B, it's fine regardless.

どっちにせよ
Whichever it be.

なんせ
Whatever the case be.

The pattern can always (well, usually) be reworded using も to mean essentially the same thing.

Ａでも、Ｂでも、なんでもいい。
どっちにしても
なんせ* (no strict conversion; maybe 何が何でも)

Comment: 「なんせ」 can be reworded as なにせ、なにしろ、なんにせよ、なんにしても, or ともかく. (It doesn't mean 何が何でも.) どうせ and なんせ are not interchangeable. どうせ = 所詮. どうせ has a nuance of 諦め、自嘲、蔑視

Comment: I know it doesn't mean 何が何でも; I was trying (too hard) to stretch the "replaceable with も in theory" point. Saying なにせ and なにしろ etc are possible replacements doesn't really help much -- they are all just different forms of the 命令形. ともかく is potentially helpful though, I would think.

Comment: `なにしろ etc are ... they are all just different forms of the 命令形` >>  「なんにしても」は 「different form of the 命令形」じゃないです。　「しても」だから命令形じゃないです。　「なんせ」の "replaceable with も in theory" には、「何が何でも」より「何にしても」のほうが使えると思いますが。

Answer (score 0):

> 今行ってもどうせ遅いので、行かないことにします。
>   Since it is late to go now, I decided not go anyway.

It is similar to "anyway". But, you should use "douse" in negative context only.